# relation between async workflows in F# and async programming

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I'm working on a report of F# async workflows, many papers I found talk about async programming model and patterns. In my understanding async workflows is just part of async programming, and async patterns are tools to write async code. I wish to know more clear relation among these terms, and what should I include in my report(as I only need to discuss async wkf only). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Asynchronous programming is a general term for out-of-sync execution, while [asynchronous workflows in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx) specifically refers to the `async` computation expression builder and the [Async functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370232.aspx). In other words, your understanding is correct: F# async workflows are a tool for the implementation of asynchronous programs.

From the book Expert F#, on terminology:

> Asynchronous programs perform requests that don't complete immediately but are fulfilled at a later time and where the program issuing the request has to do meaningful work in the meantime. For example, most network I/O (...)

A report on F# Asyncs may need a brief introduction to asynchronous programming and the usual difficulties with it, since many of the problems Asyncs solve are not issues in typical single-threaded programming. (e.g. exception propagation, memory model, thread management and blocking, cancellation)

Comment: I read some paper now, most of them did not mention the imperfections or disadvantages of async workflows. some did, but are general disadvantages of asynchronous program rather than specifically F# async workflows.Do you have any idea what F# need to improve? Thank you!

Comment: @ZHUOWEIYANG I can't say I'm an expert on Asyncs, but from what I've seen, they are well-designed. If I'd have to name things I'd wish improved in F#, I wouldn't think of Asyncs. The only "negative" thing coming to mind is that many people get confused by them at first, especially if they come from mainstream languages and don't know F# computation expressions. *Though that isn't really a disadvantage, as long as there is no simpler, comparable alternative.*